# Restricting results to only rows where one value appears only once

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate, having

I have a query that is more complex than the example here, but which needs to only return the rows where a certain field doesn't appear more than once in the data set.

```
ACTIVITY_SK      STUDY_ACTIVITY_SK
100              200
101              201
102              200
100              203
```

In this example I don't want any records with an `ACTIVITY_SK` of 100 being returned because `ACTIVITY_SK` appears twice in the data set.

The data is a mapping table, and is used in many joins, but multiple records like this imply data quality issues and so I need to simply remove them from the results, rather than cause a bad join elsewhere.

```
SELECT 
   A.ACTIVITY_SK,
   A.STATUS,
   B.STUDY_ACTIVITY_SK,
   B.NAME,
   B.PROJECT
 FROM
   ACTIVITY A,
   PROJECT B
 WHERE 
   A.ACTIVITY_SK = B.STUDY_ACTIVITY_SK
```

I had tried something like this:

```
SELECT 
   A.ACTIVITY_SK,
   A.STATUS,
   B.STUDY_ACTIVITY_SK,
   B.NAME,
   B.PROJECT
 FROM
   ACTIVITY A,
   PROJECT B
 WHERE 
   A.ACTIVITY_SK = B.STUDY_ACTIVITY_SK
 WHERE A.ACTIVITY_SK NOT IN
 (

  SELECT 
     A.ACTIVITY_SK,
     COUNT(*)
    FROM
      ACTIVITY A,
      PROJECT B
    WHERE 
    A.ACTIVITY_SK = B.STUDY_ACTIVITY_SK
    GROUP BY A.ACTIVITY_SK
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

 )
```

But there must be a less expensive way of doing this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this could be a bit "cheaper" to run:

```
SELECT
   A.ACTIVITY_SK,
   A.STATUS,
   B.STUDY_ACTIVITY_SK,
   B.NAME,
   B.PROJECT
PROJECT B INNER JOIN
   (SELECT 
       ACTIVITY_SK,
       MIN(STATUS) STATUS,
    FROM
      ACTIVITY
    GROUP BY ACTIVITY_SK
    HAVING COUNT(ACTIVITY_SK) = 1 ) A
ON A.ACTIVITY_SK = B.STUDY_ACTIVITY_SK
```

Comment: Hi, thanks...didn't think I could do a count of something I am grouping by? Looks like I can't avoid effectively running the same query twice, the join between a and b needs to take place in both queries as it is this join which creates the duplicates.

Comment: You can. Generally i don't use COUNT(*), i try always to COUNT(PK_COLUMN), since the PK has never a null value and the optimizer can use an index on that column.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

```
select * from (
  SELECT 
     A.ACTIVITY_SK,
     A.STATUS,
     B.STUDY_ACTIVITY_SK,
     B.NAME,
     B.PROJECT,
     count(distinct a.pk) over (partition by a.activity_sk) AS c
   FROM
     ACTIVITY A,
     PROJECT B
   WHERE 
     A.ACTIVITY_SK = B.STUDY_ACTIVITY_SK
) where c = 1;
```

(where `a.pk` refers to a unique identifier from the ACTIVITY table)